# Property 'info' does not exist on type 'Vue' in async method of Nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to store a response from an api in the async method of my Nuxt js application in a variable `info`. I am getting this error: `Property 'info' does not exist on type 'Vue'`. If I put the same Axios call in mounted, there is no error. This is what I have:

```
<template>
  <div>
      {{ info }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import axios from 'axios';

@Component({
  async asyncData(): Promise<any> {
    await axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response));  <--- The error is here
  },
})

export default class MainClass extends Vue {

  info: any = null;

  ....
}

</script>
```

Would appreciate some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*this* does not refer to your component. You don't have access to the component instance through this inside asyncData because it is called before initiating the component.